# Removing map elements from Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to remove a map<> from Google Cloud Firestore.

I use the following code for updating in Firestore

```
fun updateData(userId: String, values: Map<String, Any>) =
        db.collection(COLLECTION_DATA).document(Id).update(values)
```

The document contains the used id's generated for google sign in and one of the field in the document is a `map<Key,Value>` . I'm trying to delete the content of the Field (removing a specific `<key,value>` pair)

I pass `(userId, mapOf("FieldName.${Key}" to FieldValue.arrayRemove(Value)))` as the parameter while calling the above firestore function.

But after updating the value in Firestore, the key is left out and the values are cleared.

If I pass `(userId, mapOf("FieldName" to FieldValue.arrayRemove(Key)))` as the parameter, then the whole `map<>` is removed (which is what I want) but the data structure of the Field is converted as an array after performing the update.

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you're trying to remove.  Please edit the question to explain what exactly is in the document before the update, and what you want it to contain after the update.  A screenshot of the document might help if it's not easy to illustrate with text.

Comment: I've edited the question. I hope it is understandable now. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FieldValue.arrayRemove()` is for array type fields only.  It won't work here, because you're not actually using any arrays or lists.

You will just want to use [FieldValue.delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#delete()) to remove the any map key and its value.

```
updateData(userId, mapOf("FieldName.${Key}" to FieldValue.delete()))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I was trying to use FieldValue.delete before but was doing it the wrong way!