# Firestore Delete elements from a nested map kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection,  I want to delete 2 documents from this collection
[Paradas collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n034j.png)
and delete it from the nested map too
[Nested map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GItSs.png)
like in SQL, when you delete it from a table to delete it from elsewhere too.

I tried

```
fun deleteNestedParadas(lista: ArrayList<Parada> )  {
            try {
               val refrutas=Firebase.firestore.collection("rutas")
                refrutas.get().addOnSuccessListener { taskruta ->
                    for (ruta in taskruta.documents) {
                        val rutaa = ruta.toObject(Ruta::class.java)
                        if (rutaa != null) {
                            for (parada in lista) {
                                if (rutaa.paradasruta!!.contains(parada.id)) {
                                    refrutas.document(rutaa.id)
                                        .update("paradasruta",{parada.id to delete()})
                                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                                            Log.e("DeleteNestedParada",
                                                "Se han borrado las paradas correctamente")
                                        }
                                        .addOnFailureListener {
                                            Log.e("DeleteNestedParada", it.message.toString())
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
        } catch (e: Exception){
            Log.e("Nested Collection", e.message.toString())
        }
    }
```

Edit:
The error that appears is this:
After i execute the code, the whole map changes to this: "arity:0"
[image: map after error]
and appears this android error
[image: android error]

it doesn't make sense

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Besides that, which exact item would you like to delete from the Map?

Comment: It gives me the error that I edited, I want to delete a few that are included in the list, is that possible?

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: The elements in the map gets deleted, and the error is when I read from the database and then map it in the listview, but the problem is I can't get to delete any element of the map with this code. I tried different ways but it's not deleting just the specified elements that I want to delete.

Comment: What is the exact line that produces that error?

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62014960/13171940)?

Comment: Modified the code a little bit and now it works, the problem was I wasn't using mapOf, I write it like this: '.update("paradasruta", mapOf(parada.id to FieldValue.delete())) ' and now it seems to work. I tried that way before but I forgot a little detail. Thank you guys very much.

Comment: @Kytelex Could you please post your answer as a formal answer to help other users that have a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Thanks to [RogelioMonter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13171940/rogelio-monter)
and [Alex Mamo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5246885/alex-mamo) for your help.
Saw a few posts before like how to do it but it didn't work, I wasn't simply passing the mapOf to update by doing that now it works.

```
fun deleteNestedParadas(lista: ArrayList<Parada> )  {
        try {
           val refrutas=Firebase.firestore.collection("rutas")
            refrutas.get().addOnSuccessListener { taskruta ->
                for (ruta in taskruta.documents) {
                    val rutaa = ruta.toObject(Ruta::class.java)
                    if (rutaa != null) {
                        for (parada in lista) {
                            if (rutaa.paradasruta!!.contains(parada.id)) {
                                refrutas.document(rutaa.id)
                                    .update("paradasruta",mapOf{parada.id to FieldValue.delete()})
                                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                                        Log.e("DeleteNestedParada",
                                            "Se han borrado las paradas correctamente")
                                    }
                                    .addOnFailureListener {
                                        Log.e("DeleteNestedParada", it.message.toString())
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
    } catch (e: Exception){
        Log.e("Nested Collection", e.message.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.